# How to work with local storage in case of ReactJs jest testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing test cases for my ReactJs components where I have used ['react-secure-storage'](https://github.com/sushinpv/react-secure-storage). This package simply encrypts data before storing to local storage. The test file does not run and gives following error. Is there anything that I need to add in config or any workaround?

```
 PASS  src/utils/__tests__/DataStorageUtils.test.js
 PASS  src/utils/__tests__/EncryptionUtils.test.js
 PASS  src/utils/__tests__/KeyManagementUtils.test.js
 FAIL  src/components/forms/__tests__/GenerateKeysForm.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textBaseline')

      1 | import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
    > 2 | import secureLocalStorage from 'react-secure-storage';
        | ^
      3 |
      4 | class DataStorageUtils {
      5 |

      at ClientJS.getCanvasPrint (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/fingerprint.lib.js:214:24)
      at ClientJS.getFingerprint (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/fingerprint.lib.js:42:30)
      at getFingerprint (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/fingerprint.js:25:31)
      at new EncryptionService (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/encryption.js:33:47)
      at getAllLocalStorageItems (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/localStorageHelpers.js:32:19)
      at new SecureLocalStorage (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/index.js:57:64)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-secure-storage/dist/index.js:117:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/DataStorageUtils.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/forms/GenerateKeysForm.js:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/forms/__tests__/GenerateKeysForm.test.js:3:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Tests:       13 passed, 13 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.323 s
```

Below is my package.json and setupTests.js.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "km",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "eosjs-ecc": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-secure-storage": "^1.0.21",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0"
  }
}
```

setupTests.js

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Comment: Hi @XCEPTION, I'm the creator of react-secure-storage library and the library is created on top of a concept called browser fingerprint and this is highly depends on the underlying browser this code is running on, so when you write a unit test case without mocking the browser APIs, it will throw this error, so can you open one issue on the GitHub with the exact error you are getting and with the gist of test case you are trying to run, so that I'll suggest you in how to proceed with a temporary fix and I'll patch this fix on the main library itself